# e.PreventDefault() not working when text is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I am trying to create a music playlist on my website. I have where the music plays when I click the different text. However, I want it to do where it will not take me to a page for the song to play. I have tried to use a `e.PrevetnDefault()` for this to work, hoping that it would cancel my page opening a new page when the text is clicked on. However, it is not working. Whenever I click on the texts, a page opens.

A look at my code:

```
   <script>
    audioPlayer();

    function audioPlayer() {
        var currentSong = 0;
        $("audioPlayer")[0].src = $("DJList li a")[0];
        $("audioPlayer")[0].play();
        $("DJList li a").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = this;
            $("audioPlayer")[0].play();
            $("#DJList li a").removeClass("current-song");
            currentSong = $(this).parent().index();
            $(this).parent.addClass("current-song");
        });

        $("audioPlayer")[0].addEventListener("ended", function() {
            currentSong++
            if (currentSong == $("DJList li a").length)
                currentSong = 0;
            $("DJList li").removeClass("current-song");
            $("DJList li:eq(" + currentSong + ")").addClass("current-song");
            $("audioPlayer")[0].src = $("DJList li a")[currentSong].href;
            $("audioPlayer")[0].play();
        });
</script>
```

Comment: because you're using "DJList" without "#" as a selector in various places

Comment: Adding a closing brace wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: That too, and check all your selectors, there's about a dozen wrong

Comment: btw, `#` is element id. Use `.` for class selectors

Comment: A thing that might help you in the future is the console, to fix simple errors like these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("DJList li a").click(function(e) {` won't select your link since `DJList` isn't any element name that'll get selected.
Hence your preventDefault isn't even getting called. 
Changing it to `$("#DJList li a")` might do for starters. You have the same mistake at multiple places.